# Are there SIMD instructions to speed up checksum calculations?

Tags: c++, checksum, simd

I'm going to have to code a very basic checksum function, something like:

```
char sum(const char * data, const int len)
{
    char sum(0);
    for (const char * end=data+len ; data<end ; ++data)
        sum += *data;
    return sum;
}
```

That's trivial. Now, how should I optimize this?
First, I should probably use some std::for_each with a lambda or something like that:

```
char sum2(const char * data, const int len)
{
    char sum(0);
    std::for_each(data, data+len, [&sum](char b){sum+=b;});
    return sum;
}
```

Next, I could use multiple threads/cores to sum up chunks, then add the results. I won't write it down, and I'm afraid the cost of creating threads (or getting them from a pool anyway), then cutting up the array, then dispatching everything, etc, would not be very good considering that I would mostly calculate checksums for small arrays, mostly 10-100 bytes, rarely up to 1000.

But what I really want is something lower level, some SIMD stuff that would sum up bytes on 128b registers, or maybe sum bytes independently between two registers without carrying the carry, or both.

Is there any such thing out there ?

Note: This IS actual premature optimization, but it's fun, so what the hell?

**Edit:** I still need a way to sum up all the bytes in an SSE register, something better than

```
char ptr[16];
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)ptr, sum);
checksum += ptr[0] + ptr[1] + ptr[2]  + ptr[3]  + ptr[4]  + ptr[5]  + ptr[6]  + ptr[7]
          + ptr[8] + ptr[9] + ptr[10] + ptr[11] + ptr[12] + ptr[13] + ptr[14] + ptr[15];
```

Comment: I have no actual proof of this, but I suspect the `std::for_each` version is going to be slower than the manual method...

Comment: I'm assuming you want Intel opps here?

Comment: @Mike Depends, it is actually slower for small packets but faster for big ones. I've tested with 100b and 900b, I don't know where the limit is for my set-up. I guess the cost of object creation has to do with this. Unsurprisingly, SSE beat both for both sizes.

Comment: @Gabriel: It is not a premature optimization. In my project, for example, it was a slowest place. At first I unrolled it by 4, which gave a lot of boost, but it was still the slowest. So I had to re-write it using SSE intrinsics. And it is fun! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are such instructions in the MMX instruction set, called "Packed ADD":

- [`_mm_add_pi8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/06wxs3hb.aspx) in Visual C++
- `__builtin_ia32_paddb` in gcc

And in the SSE2 instruction set:

- [`_mm_add_epi8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc7tcyzs.aspx) in Visual C++
- `__builtin_ia32_paddb128` in gcc

EDIT: A faster way to add the partial sums:

```
__m128i sums;

sums = _mm_add_epi8(sums, _mm_srli_si128(sums, 1));
sums = _mm_add_epi8(sums, _mm_srli_si128(sums, 2));
sums = _mm_add_epi8(sums, _mm_srli_si128(sums, 4));
sums = _mm_add_epi8(sums, _mm_srli_si128(sums, 8));
checksum += _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sums);
```

Comment: Now, is any compiler badass enough to produce the right code given the loops above?

Comment: I can't imagine that most compilers would bother to emit SSE for that first loop. It's annoying to try to load from an arbitrary pointer—the compiler doesn't know if the target is aligned, and if it can load in SSE-sized chunks, and so on.

Comment: No need to use compiler names here. GCC as well as Visual C++ support the standard MMX/SSE extension headers and functions. I'm no MMX/SSE user, but check for example `<mmintrin.h>` for protoypes.

Comment: The trick for the horizontal sum at the end is `psadbw` / `_mm_sad_epu8` against zero to sum 8-byte chunks in each 64-bit half: [Fastest way to horizontally sum SSE unsigned byte vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36998538)

Answer (score -2):

Look at _mm_add_ps. Simultaneous add of 128-bit contiguous block. You'll need to zero pad your array or process the last few non SIMD style.