# result with/without SSE simd operation is different

Tags: c++, sse

i'm trying to sum all the element of array (unsigned char)

but the result of cv::Mat sum is different from SSE result(below code)

with sse, sum of array result bigger than without, but why??

ex) i got 2042115 for sse sum, but cv::mat's sum results 2041104.

```
__m128i srcVal;
        __m128i src16bitlo;
        __m128i src16bithi;
        __m128i src32bitlolo;
        __m128i src32bitlohi;
        __m128i src32bithilo;
        __m128i src32bithihi;
        __m128i vsum = _mm_setzero_si128();
    for (int i = 0; i < nSrcSize; i += 16)
    {

        srcVal = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) (pSrc + i));

        src16bitlo = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(srcVal, _mm_setzero_si128());
        src16bithi = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(srcVal, _mm_setzero_si128());

        src32bitlolo = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(src16bitlo, _mm_setzero_si128());
        src32bitlohi = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(src16bitlo, _mm_setzero_si128());
        src32bithilo = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(src16bithi, _mm_setzero_si128());
        src32bithihi = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(src16bithi, _mm_setzero_si128());

        vsum = _mm_add_epi32(src32bitlolo, vsum);
        vsum = _mm_add_epi32(src32bitlohi, vsum);
        vsum = _mm_add_epi32(src32bithilo, vsum);
        vsum = _mm_add_epi32(src32bithihi, vsum);


        // cout << "sumSrc : " << sumSrc << endl;
    }
    int sumSrc = vsum.m128i_i32[0] + vsum.m128i_i32[1] + vsum.m128i_i32[2] + vsum.m128i_i32[3];
    //int check = sumSrc;

    int remainSize = nSrcSize % 16;
    if (remainSize > 0)
    {
        unsigned char* arrTemp = new unsigned char[16]();  // 0으로 초기화
        memcpy(arrTemp, pSrc + nSrcSize - remainSize -1, remainSize);
        __m128i srcVal = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)arrTemp);
        vsum = _mm_sad_epu8(srcVal, _mm_setzero_si128());
        sumSrc += vsum.m128i_i16[0] + vsum.m128i_i16[1] + vsum.m128i_i16[2] + vsum.m128i_i16[3] + vsum.m128i_i16[4] + vsum.m128i_i16[5] + vsum.m128i_i16[6] + vsum.m128i_i16[7];
    }
```

Comment: FYI, `psadbw` against zero will horizontal sum a vector of unsigned char into two qwords much more efficiently than your SIMD loop. [Fastest way to horizontally sum SSE unsigned byte vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36998538).   See also how [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54541129) uses it.

Comment: Oh, you're already using `psadbw` in the cleanup, but you're adding up all 8 of the 16-bit elements, even though 6 of them are zero.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh i got it. thank you!

Comment: If my answer (which also expanded on those comments) solved your problem, you can "accept" it with the checkmark under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 bugs:

**`i < nSrcSize` can be true when the final vector extends past `nSrcSize`**.  Since you're already using signed `int i`, you can use `i < nSrcSize - 15` to find the highest `i` value that can load a full 16 bytes from `i+0` to `i+15`.  Or use `nSrcSize & -16U` if you're using size_t.

**`new unsigned char[16]()` doesn't zero the memory**, so you're summing some extra garbage.  You do *not* need `new`, and you forgot to delete it so you're leaking that memory!  You *could* use a local array, not dynamically allocating anything.

```
alignas(16) unsigned char arrTemp[16] = {0};  // implicitly initializes later elements to 0
```

But that variable-size memcpy is not great for efficiency, and reloading the memcpy result will cause a store-forwarding stall.  OTOH, you can just `_mm_add_epi32(vsum, cleanup_sad)` and only do one horizontal vector sum.

Even more efficient might be branching yourself on the size (instead of passing the work to memcpy) and doing an 8-byte and 4-byte chunk with SIMD loads.  Or once there are fewer than 8 bytes left, do an 8-byte load that won't cross a cache-line boundary to get it all.

Check if a load that starts at the first byte you want would cross a 64-byte boundary.  If no, do it and 64-bit left shift to shift in zeros, which you can safely hsum.  If yes, then do a load that *ends* with the *last* byte you want, and do a right shift.  You have to calculate the shift count as `8 * (8 - bytes_to_keep)`.  You can use a scalar shift and then `_mm_cvtsi64_si128` into a SIMD vector, or directly `_mm_loadl_epi64` (`movq`) and use a SIMD shift.  (Unfortunately SSE/AVX doesn't have variable-count byte-shifts, only bit-shifts, and the count needs to be in another SIMD vector.)

---

FYI, `psadbw` against zero will horizontal sum a vector of unsigned char into two qwords much more efficiently than your SIMD loop. [Fastest way to horizontally sum SSE unsigned byte vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36998538). See also how [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54541129) uses it in the outer loop to accumulate vectors of bytes into a SIMD vector with wider elements.

You're already using `psadbw` in the cleanup, but you're adding up all eight of the 16-bit elements, even though six of them are zero.

Comment: i changed my code. but it seems problem is in first part of the code, not from processing remain part.

Comment: @LakesideStar: Oh, you also have another bug: `i < nSrcSize` can be true when the final vector extends past `nSrcSize`.  Since you're already using signed `int i`, you can use `i < nSrcSize - 15` to find the highest `i` value that can load a full 16 bytes from `i+0` to `i+15`.  Or use `nSrcSize & -16U` if you're using size_t.