# Program in C++ that calculates the sum of unsigned char array of 80 elements using MMX instructions through inline assembly programming

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, mmx

`I am trying a program in C++ that declares an unsigned char array of 80 elements and initializes every element with "1." The program then calculates the sum of these 80 elements using MMX instructions through inline assembly programming and displays it on screen.

Hint i am given is  the last eight bytes would be summed serially.
I tried `

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char dataArray[80];
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; ++i) {
        dataArray[i] = 1;
    }

    unsigned char sum;

    __asm {
        pxor mm0, mm0
        movq mm1, [dataArray]
        movq mm2, sum

        add_loop:
        movq mm3, [mm1]
        paddb mm0, mm3
        add mm1, 8
        dec ecx
        jnz add_loop
        movq sum, mm0
        emms
    }

    std::cout << "Sum: " << static_cast<int>(sum) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result
Sum of last eight elements: -1179010631
instead of 80 please help regarding this

Comment: *Hint i am given is the last eight bytes would be summed serially.* - there's a trick for that, too, with the extended MMX instructions added as part of SSE1: `psadbw` against a zeroed register. (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psadbw).  So `pxor mm3, mm3` / `psadbw mm0, xmm3` / `movd sum, mm0` (Declare `sum` as `uint32_t` so you don't have to extract to an integer register first to store a byte without SSE4 `pextrb`)

Comment: Also, MMX registers don't work as pointers; use integer registers for that, that's what they're for.  If your compiler didn't produce an error on `movq mm3, [mm1]` or `add mm1, 8`, get a new compiler. (MSVC 19.10 and `clang -fam-blocks` reject it with an error: https://godbolt.org/z/M1GKPzsW3). Those aren't valid instructions!  See [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926) for some examples of looping a pointer over an array and adding, with a 16-byte XMM register with SSE2 instead of obsolete MMX, but same difference.

Comment: Anyway, the simplistic way to sum the 8 bytes of `mm0` would be with `movq` to a `uint8_t bytes[8]` and loop over that, if you don't want to do it [efficiently with `psadbw`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998538/fastest-way-to-horizontally-sum-sse-unsigned-byte-vector) or with shuffles like `pshufw` / `paddb` for 2 steps then a byte shift like `movq` + `psrlw mm, 8` for byte granularity  (as in [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764)

Comment: The key point I think you're missing is that each byte of `mm0` has the sum of every 8th byte of your array.  Like unrolling a loop with `sum0+=arr[i]`, `sum1+=arr[i+1]` etc.  So you can't just store it and print the whole thing as a 32 or 64-bit integer.  `-1179010631` is `0xb9b9b9b9`, which isn't `80/8 = 10 = 0x0a` like you'd expect if the array indexing worked, but it's also not plausible that you could get a value outside the `0..255` range from C++ code for x86 that's reading an `unsigned char`.  (Which is 1 byte wide but you stored 8).