GCC generates slow code when targeting more recent sse version
I have very simple test program like below. Just sum all uint8 values in array.
GCC seems to generate significantly slower code when targeting sse4 or avx2.
Code is significantly faster with ssse3.
Is it possible to modify the sum function to work also fast with sse4 without writing custom intrinsics? Or it is gcc issue as it generates worse assembly for higher sse level in this particular use case?
I wanted to target my codebase to sse4 but noticed such a few slowdowns in some performance tests.
https://godbolt.org/z/GcKj3reGv
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

float  
__attribute__ ((noinline)) 
__attribute__((target("ssse3")))
testsse3(unsigned char* data, int size)
{
    unsigned char* end = data + size;
     long long sum = 0;
    while(data < end)
    {
        sum += (long long)(*data++);
    }

    return sum;
}

float  
__attribute__ ((noinline)) 
__attribute__((target("sse4")))
testsse4(unsigned char* data, int size)
{
    unsigned char* end = data + size;
    long long sum = 0;
    while(data < end)
    {
        sum += (long long)(*data++);
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int sse3 = 9999;
    int sse4 = 9999;
    const int len = 1000000;
    unsigned char* d = new unsigned char[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        d[i] = (unsigned char)i;
    float total = 0;
    for(int i= 0; i < 100; ++i){
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point be = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        total += testsse3(d, len);
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point ee = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto r1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(ee - be).count();
        sse3 = std::min(sse3, (int)r1);
    }
    for(int i= 0; i < 100; ++i){
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point be = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        total += testsse4(d, len);
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point ee = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto r2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(ee - be).count();
        sse4 = std::min(sse4, (int)r2);
    }
    
    printf("sse3: %d sse4: %d\n", sse3, sse4);
    return (int)total;
}

My results are like:
sse3: 152 sse4: 190

The code seems indeed slower on modern Intel CPUs (from Skylake to RocketLake). It is mainly due to a saturation of the port 5. This port is AFAIR responsible to do shuffles and shifts. It is a known limitation of such architecture (AFAIK Intel explicitly provide information about how to reduce the pressure on this port in its optimization manual). It is quite common for the code to be bound by this port unfortunately. Compilers are not perfect and sometimes they poorly optimize codes.  Note that GCC does not know what is the target CPU architecture (though it is not better when it does).

Note that performance results on Godbolt are not reliable. If you add useless options, then timings strongly change because they are not stable at all. For example with -O3 -g -g I get :  sse3: 253 sse4: 287. With -O3 -g -g -g I get sse3: 139 sse4: 187. Clang produce a better code with SSE4 than GCC and does not even vectorize the code with SSE3. Same thing for ICX though the code is even better for SSE3 than Clang (and so GCC).

I think this question should be more relevant on the GCC bug tracker than here.

Not an answer to why GCC messes up, but the fastest way to sum unsigned bytes should be using psadbw and paddq: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998538/fastest-way-to-horizontally-sum-sse-unsigned-byte-vector (actually needs only SSE2)

@JérômeRichard I just pasted minimal scenario to Godbolt. All testing I do on my local PC. I have attached source code to easily reproduce it on local PC. I've expected that such quite simple loops are well vectorized today by recent compilers, but it seems not to be true.

I tested your code out of curiosity, and I have pretty much the same with GCC. I just wanted to highlight that you are printing-out the minimum times that have been detected inside your loops, while inside those loop there were quite some jumps, but your testsse4 function was more stable than its testsse3 counterpart. So guess there is not just a compiler issue but some internal CPU-magic as well.
